# Empty `begin end` at the end of a Ruby script

Tags: ruby

I've just found a Ruby script that ends with the following lines:

```
exit

begin

end
```

To me, this looks pointless; but the developer who wrote the script was not normally one to do daft things.

Does this actually achieve anything? Some kind of fix for a known bug in Ruby, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can gather, no. it has no meaning and no function and no function. Nothing after exit is parsed (not entirely true [1], but in this case it is), and an empty begin end is not really useful either.

I would think it's a simple oversight during development/cleaning/refactoring. Even good developers make mistakes of course.

So the easiest way to be sure of his intentions, is to ask the author, of course!

[1] http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-exit